# Can CSS div height 100% with liquid parents work?

Tags: css

So if the parent div's height is 100% then you can set the child to 100% and it will work.
But if the parent's height is decided by content then the height attribute doesn't seem to work.

Is there a decent workaround that would work on most browsers?

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#content img
{
    display: block;
}
#left
{
    float: left;
}
#right
{
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    border: thin solid;
    height: 100%;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="content">
    <div id="left">
        <img src="images/dc_logo.png"/>
        <img src="images/dc_logo.png"/>
        <img src="images/dc_logo.png"/>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        stretch full height plz
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't, and it's a shame.  There are little tricks to emulate the effect, but those are situational.  For example, if you have a sidebar and a main content area, you can surround them in a container, and give the container a background the repeats vertically to look like it's the sidebar.  Or you can use JavaScript to dynamically calculate the size onload.  But unfortunately, purely CSS-wise you're stuck.